# How to Delete Application Jump List in Windows Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, start-menu, jumplist, pinning

Does anyone know how to delete the MRU list for Excel in the start menu? (See screen capture.) I think the list on my machine is corrupted because I cannot delete/unpin anything on it. Reinstalling Office did not help. I'm running Windows 7 Pro and Office 2016.

[image]

Comment: is this a possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4692594/2203750)? though the Operating System may vary

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate of that question.  I actually saw that post and tried that very solution before making my post.  All it does is delete the list of most recently used applications, which is why my most recently used application list in the start menu is so sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution to the problem on [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5245/fix-for-when-pinned-jump-list-items-get-stuck-in-windows-7/):

> *What we can do to resolve this problem is delete the file that caches
>   the pinned items. You can see those files for yourself by opening up
>   an Explorer window and pasting in the following path:*
>
> **%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations**
>
> *Unfortunately, all of these files are not human-readable, though you
>   can kinda/sorta figure out what they are assigned to by opening them
>   up in Notepad. The key thing to know is that there seems to be one of
>   these per application.*